# Why do I not get any matches when I use regex?

Tags: android, json, regex

I am trying to understand how to use regex in android studio. I am trying to get some catchgroups from a Json response string. I know that you should probably parse the json objects the normal way but I want to figure out why my rgex is not working.

I have tried pasting the json string into a online regex checker and I am able to get all catchgroups I want by using something like:

```
topLeftX.+\s(\d+)|topLeftY.+\s(\d+)
```

But that does not work for me in android studio as I don't get any matches.

This is the test I have tried:

```
JSONObject json_raw = null;

        try {
            json_raw = new JSONObject("{\n" +
                    "    \"images\": [\n" +
                    "        {\n" +
                    "            \"status\": \"Complete\",\n" +
                    "            \"width\": 1536,\n" +
                    "            \"height\": 2048,\n" +
                    "            \"file\": \"kairos-elizabeth.jpg\",\n" +
                    "            \"faces\": [\n" +
                    "                {\n" +
                    "                    \"topLeftX\": 390,\n" +
                    "                    \"topLeftY\": 706,\n" +
                    "                    \"chinTipX\": 780,\n" +
                    "                    \"rightEyeCenterX\": 587,\n" +
                    "                    \"yaw\": -3,\n" +
                    "                    \"chinTipY\": 1548,\n" +
                    "                    \"confidence\": 0.99997,\n" +
                    "                    \"height\": 780,\n" +
                    "                    \"rightEyeCenterY\": 904,\n" +
                    "                    \"width\": 781,\n" +
                    "                    \"leftEyeCenterY\": 907,\n" +
                    "                    \"leftEyeCenterX\": 955,\n" +
                    "                    \"pitch\": -17,\n" +
                    "                    \"attributes\": {\n" +
                    "                        \"lips\": \"Together\",\n" +
                    "                        \"asian\": 0.25658,\n" +
                    "                        \"gender\": {\n" +
                    "                            \"type\": \"F\"\n" +
                    "                        },\n" +
                    "                        \"age\": 26,\n" +
                    "                        \"hispanic\": 0.41825,\n" +
                    "                        \"other\": 0.11144,\n" +
                    "                        \"black\": 0.16007,\n" +
                    "                        \"white\": 0.05365,\n" +
                    "                        \"glasses\": \"None\"\n" +
                    "                    },\n" +
                    "                    \"face_id\": 1,\n" +
                    "                    \"quality\": 0.79333,\n" +
                    "                    \"roll\": -1\n" +
                    "                }\n" +
                    "            ]\n" +
                    "        }\n" +
                    "    ]\n" +
                    "}");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("topLeftX.+\\s(\\d+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(json_raw.toString());
```

Comment: You have a valid JSON string, you should fetch your data using JSON method for better result...

Comment: You create a matcher `Matcher` object but you don't seem to use it? Note that in your case you want to do `matcher.find()` rather than `matcher.matches()`.

Comment: I've given you snippet how to process those JSON string using Android's JSON method. Please see that and also learn some JSON handling for more...

Answer (score 0):

So, you already have a valid JSON object, for better code, you should use [JSON methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) to fetch your data. Correct me if I'm wrong, I think you want to get `topLeftX` and `topLeftY` information.

[image: This is the representation of your JSON]

To do that using JSON, here's some snippet:

```
JSONArray images = json_raw.getJSONArray("images");
for(int i = 0; i < images.length(); i++){
    JSONArray faces = images.getJSONArray(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < faces.length(); j++){
        JSONObject face = faces.getJSONObject(j)
        Log.d("LOG", "Top Left X: " + face.getInt("topLeftX");
        Log.d("LOG", "Top Left Y: " + face.getInt("topLeftY");
    }
}
```

> Please note that my code is untested, but it is based on the actual API, there's some `catch` code need to be present (or you can `throw` it all)

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error, It says that object can not be converted to an array.

Comment: what line is the error, also, you should learn how to use Android's JSON methods first to understand what my codes trying to do...